# Writing a MYSQL REGEXP: greedy vs negated confusion

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking for some help with a regular expression for a MYSQL query. I'm fairly new to expressions and have gotten myself thoroughly confused.

My database cell looks something like this

```
1314{{Here is some data}}1213{{More data here}}1112{{Data ahoy}}
```

And I'm trying to write an expression that'll attempt to match the set of data, but only the data within the bracketed year.

For example, say that **$year=1314** and **$term="ahoy"**.

With the below REGEXP:

```
$year\{\{.* $term.*\}\}
```

It returns a match - because it's matching the final "}}" of the 1112 prefixed dataset. I don't want it to do this, but despite reading up on this greedy / negated business, I can't get the syntax to work.
What would the best way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: So to clarify, "data" would match for 1314 and "here" would match for 1213 but "ahoy" should not match for 1213 and "data" should not match for 1213?

Comment: Do you want to match nothing for your current example? And if `$year` was `1112` and `$term` was `ahoy`, you want to match the last part? Is it like that?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I'm confusing myself now! Yes, Rohit Jain, you're right: so in the example, nothing would match, but if the year was 1112, there would be a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$year\{\{[^}]*$term[^}]*\}\}
```

Where `[^}]*` matches anything not a `}` so it will stop matching when it hits the first occurrence of `}`

`.*` is greedy so it will match the last occurrence possible so `.*\}\}` matches the last set of `}}` to make it non-greedy you can use a `?` like `.*?\}\}` but I prefer using negation.